# How can I connect a side with many vertices to a side with much fewer to produce a clean looking topology?

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to learn topology by modeling difficult shapes, in this case a gaming mouse. I'm getting stuck with two problems with this model.

The first one is that I have no idea how to connect two sides with much different number of vertices. As you can see below, I try to reduce the vertices on one side but it ends up messy as hell.

[image: Uneven quad all over the mesh]

The second issue I'm facing is the unexpected pinch when I try to pull along the z axis the middle line in the left click & right click shape.

[image: Unexpected pinch]

[image: Its topology]

How can I solve these problems? I've watched some topology videos from CG Cookie and understood some topology concepts, but I still struggle to get all the decisions right when connecting the vertices. What do you base your decisions on when connecting the remaining parts after finishing setting up all the main loops that support the main features?

My Blender file: [Logitech_G600.blend](https://gofile.io/?c=KhQxOC)

Updated: I've just reworked the model and come up with this:

[image: Still look messy]

Edit: English

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the correct thing - trying to reduce the amount of vertices on one side. That should work. The idea is to have as little of geometry as possible that would still hold the forms you need, because the fewer points and lines you have to worry about, the easier it is to work with them. You can see the opposite on the unexpected pinch where you have too much geometry so it's not that easy to smooth or correct. You have way too much unnecessary geometry there. I would delete a lot.

In this particular situation it seems you might already have too much geometry to be able to replicate the forms. It is different from the reference object and you already have so many lines and vertices that it would be difficult to move them into places.

[image: Shapes]

These shapes needed to be addressed earlier in the modelling process. It might be easier to start over then to fix it. That might be frustrating, but I think everyone goes trough a lot of redoing when learning this. I certainly did. With this kind of object it may be hard to understand what the forms are, so I would start by establishing all the lines that I understand from the start(in 3d). I would only make a vertex and extrude it into lines and check the position looking from multiple sides, like from top and side views. Then I would try to connect them and this way I could add or remove points as needed while connecting the lines.  I would aim to use only as many vertices as it is needed and not one more carefully observing if the forms generated by Subsurf modifier are matching the reference. I cannot advise any further without actually modelling the thing I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you for offering help, Martin. I've updated the file link with packed image. I've also updated the rework, still look messy. To be honest, that's probably the best I can do with my current knowledge. I would really appreciate it if you show me the way.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I've redone it last night and made this: https://ibb.co/fQV9JRQ. Although it forms the shapes I want to make and allow good deformation using Lattice, I still find the topology a little bit messy. I guess I will move on to other project and learn something else, then to go back to fix this in the future.